# How to Restore a deleted folder in the Visual Studio Code Recycle Bin Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, recycle-bin

I'm working in an angular project using Vscode , by mistake i deleted a folder component that contains 3 files one html file and 2 ts files and the folder is deleted also from my Recycle Bin. im trying to recover the folder for 2 days I installed 3 software for file recovery and I couldn't find my folder it's very strange no recovery software can find this deleted folder.
can you please help me?
I'm using Windows and I didn't use Git in this project.

thanks in advance

Comment: Your files are gone. There's no such thing as "Visual studio code recycle bin".

Comment: why recovery software can't find it ?

Comment: Some lessons are learned the hard way. This time, the lesson learned should be "use git and commit frequently"

Comment: Use git and don't delete the `.git` folder

Comment: @rioV8 didn't use git before deleting the folder

Comment: I mean if you use git you have the same problem if you delete the repository on your harddisk and you don't have a backup somewhere on a different medium

Answer (score 2):

#### For VSCode

Deleted files may be recover from below directory. In directory all files have formatted name.

`C:\Users\{YourUserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\History`

As an example, if old file's name was `mycode.c` and you could see your code in `f0s8242` file. So you should open all files and read which is the same as old code.